# PersistenceManagerFactory not initialized while accessing wookie in tomcat

Tags: tomcat6

I am trying wookie inside tomcat. Whenever I try to run wookie through (http://localhost:8080/wookie) I get the following log.

```
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke  
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception  
java.lang.RuntimeException: PersistenceManagerFactory not initialized  
        at org.apache.wookie.beans.util.PersistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceManager  (PersistenceManagerFactory.java:296)
        at org.apache.wookie.server.MainFilter.doFilter(MainFilter.java:51)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:558)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
```

I have followed the instructions at wookie docs (incubator.apache.org/wookie/downloading-and-installing-wookie.html)

and this is my [build.properties](http://uploading.com/files/9651mf6f/build.properties/) file and uploading.com/files/6cb5582d/build.xml file

What could be the possible causes of above problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
servletEngine.context.conf.dir=CATALINA_HOME/conf/Catalina/localhost
```

DO NOT MISS Catalina/localhost after conf. otherwise above mentioned problems will occur. I still do not know why it wants Catalina/localhost path instead if just conf dir path!!